# Calulcating consecutive months in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to apply the following logic in R:

1. I already have grou_by the data by Donor.ID
2. The first step is to identify the Firs.Date, which is the first donation
3. What I need is to check on each donor if there has been a donation, meaning another row which a date that is within 3 months of the first.Date, so for the example below, I would use mutate to create another column, let's call it Drop.Out and then add the logic that detects if a donation happened within 3 months of the first donation, in that case Donor.ID 1 will have a 1, and Donor.ID 2 will have a 0, simply because there was not a donation (row enrtry) within 3 months from the first date.

I know that it should be surprisingly easy, but somehow I can't get it to work.

[image: Data Frame]

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example data instead of images.

Comment: Could you show us how your desired output would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used lubridate to make a duration from the first time in every group to the current time, and some basic summarization to check if any values meet the criteria. Let me know if this works.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

df <- tribble(
  ~Donor.id, ~Date,
  1, "2019-01-01",
  1, "2019-02-03",
  1, "2019-03-03",
  1, "2019-06-12",
  1, "2019-06-23",
  2, "2019-03-01",
  2, "2019-07-01",
  2, "2019-08-01",
) %>%
  mutate(Date = parse_date_time(Date, "%y-%m-%d"))


df %>%
  group_by(Donor.id) %>%
  mutate(Drop.Out = (first(Date) %--% Date)/dmonths(1) != 0 
  & (first(Date) %--% Date)/dmonths(1) <= 3) %>%
  summarise(Drop.Out = any(Drop.Out))
```